# IE Scroll Bar Not Visable for Colorbox Modal

Tags: jquery, scrollbar

I am using the ColorBox modal and I am having a problem with the ScrollBar Not showing up on IE browsers. Has anyone else ever had this problem?

The Page I am Using is : (CLICK SAMPLE SAVINGS TO SEE) : 
http://whiterhino.us/aspire_setup/

Does it have to do with a jQuery Line 4 Error? I am not seeing a problem with line 4.

Thank You Very Much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to style your **modal-window-savings** div container in your iframe (http://whiterhino.us/aspire_setup/savings.html) to have a height of 100%.  You then will have scollbars in IE when you open the modal window.

```
<div id="modal-window-savings" style='height: 100%;'>
```